# Have there been (more) reflights of a manned space mission?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight

In recent question about color blindness there was an interesting fact about two back-to-back space shuttle missions, STS-83 and STS-94, that were flown with same shuttle and same crew with only few months apart. The reason was that STS-83 was cut short due to failure of a fuel cell.

My question is have there been any other missions, or individual crew members, that have been sent up "again" to complete a task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is have there been any other missions, or individual crew
>   members, that have been sent up "again" to complete a task?

[STS-75](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-75)'s main payload was a reflight of [STS-46's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-46) main payload due to the failure of the [Tethered Satellite System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tether_missions#Shuttle_TSS_missions) (TSS) on its first attempt. Sadly, STS-75 failed as well, but in a different way, ending this system's flight attempts, and kicking off a large number of silly UFO theories.

It wasn't an exact mission reflight like 83/94, but several crew members who were trained in operating the TSS flew on both: [Nicollier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Nicollier), [Chang-Diaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_R._Chang-Diaz), and [Hoffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_A._Hoffman).

- On STS-46 the tether jammed in the deployer after the satellite had only been deployed a short distance.  This was traced to "fixes" made to the deployer shortly before launch.
  [image]
- On STS-75 the tether broke after deploying a significant distance. 
  This was traced to manufacturing errors with the tether.

[image]

Another example is [Charles Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_D._Walker) who flew on three separate shuttle missions to operate the McDonnell Douglas experiment Electrophoresis Operations in Space.

[image]

This wasn't due to a mission or experiment failure though, but was part of the pre-Challenger-failure attempts to commercialize the Shuttle.  Walker was the first non-government/commercial astronaut in history.

Comment: Given that your knowledge of shuttle operations is vast and it is unlikely that similar missions would’ve happened in other space programs I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you for taking time to answer.

Comment: Thanks. There were other possibilities of payloads repeatedly flown on shuttle (Wakeshield, SPAS, SPARTAN) but without the same crew.